# How to allow to make my REST API end point be called via ajax as well as http libraries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rest, http

I have a main REST web app where I have an endpoint: POST /api/v1/my_endpoint

I want to allow it to be called:

1) via a browser via ajax from my other web apps on different domains

2) from a server side via HTTP client library.

In the case of ajax call - #1 - I'll have to include "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin" and the similar headers to my response to let a browser receive a response.

In the case #2 - I won't need to include those headers.

However, there's no reliable way to distinguish between #1 and #2.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, you check for the presence of an `Origin` header. This header is sent by the browser as part of the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) protocol. To explain how it works, below is a filter (in other frameworks, this is also known as middleware) used by a Jersey application. Jersey is a Java REST framework. Sorry I don't know Rails. But you should still be able to follow along with this explanation,.

How this filter works is that the `ContiainerRequestFilter` is called before the backend controller method is called, then the controller method is called, then the `ContainerResponseFilter` is called. See the commented notes above the methods to see which method are for which.

```java
public class CorsFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    // ******************************************
    // implementation for ContainerRequestFilter
    // ******************************************
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        if (isPreflightRequest(request)) {
            request.abortWith(Response.ok().build());
            return;
        }
    }

    private static boolean isPreflightRequest(ContainerRequestContext request) {
        return request.getHeaderString("Origin") != null
                && request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS");
    }

    @Override
    // ******************************************
    // implementation for ContainerResponseFilter
    // ******************************************
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response)
            throws IOException {
        if (request.getHeaderString("Origin") == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (isPreflightRequest(request)) {
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-Token, " +
                "Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5,  Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name");
        }
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }
}
```

So when the request comes in, the filter checks to see if it is [Preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request). There are two types of cross origin request: a normal one, and preflight. The preflight request occurs before the actual request is made to the server. This is an `OPTIONS` request where the browser sends some CORS request headers to check with the server to see if the request is allowed. The server should respond back with CORS response headers telling the server that the request is allowed.

So with this filter, is it a preflight request, we abort the request (the controller method will not be called) and then the code execution goes to the `ContainerResponseFilter` where we set the CORS response headers. You can see in the code, we check the same `isPreflightRequest()` method.

If the request is not an `OPTIONS` request, and the `Origin` header *is* present, then it is a "normal" cross origin request, in which case, all that is required in in the response headers is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Notice that if there is no `Origin` header, then no CORS headers are added. This is basically how you will differentiate from an AJAX client and other HTTP clients. Only AJAX requests will add the `Origin` header, and this is done automatically by the browser when it detects a cross origin request.

I hope you understand everything I am talking about, even though the code is Java. It think it's pretty straight forward though, even if you have never used Java. The naming or methods and variables should make it easy to follow. If you understand the flow of the code, then you should pretty much understand the flow of the CORS protocol.

#### Aside

As an aside, it doesn't hurt if you add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on *all* responses, whether it be an AJAX request or an HTTP client request. If you want to be lazy and implement it this way, it won't hurt. It is required for the AJAX client, but not for the HTTP client. But if you include it in the HTTP client, nobody will die. The world will go on business as usual.

Comment: you didn't answer my question

Comment: And what was your question? How to distinguish between Ajax client and other clients? If so, yes I did answer it. You know it's an Ajax client in a cross origin request because of presence of an `Origin` header. This is not a standard HTTP header. It is a header specific to the CORS protocol and is only added by the browser on cross origin requests. Other than that, I don't see any other questions on your post.